# Form Validation message not being displayed - Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm having trouble getting error messages in Flask to render.
I suspect this is related to the blueprints. Previously, the logic seen in views.py was in the users blueprint, but I've since ported it over to the main blueprint. Anyhow, since then, I am unable to get error messages to render.

The specific line I think I'm having trouble with is:

self.email.errors.append("This Email is already registered")

## project/main/views.py

```
@main_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@main_blueprint.route('/<referrer>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home(referrer=None):

    form = RegisterForm(request.form)

    # prepares response
    resp = make_response(render_template('main/index.html', form=form))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       do_stuff()
    return resp
```

## project/main/index.html

```
<h1>Please Register</h1>
<br>
<form class="" role="form" method="post" action="">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
  {{ form.email(placeholder="email") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if form.email.errors %}
        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  </p>
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Register!</button>
  <br><br>
  <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Sign in</a>.</p>
</form>
```

## project/user/forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
        email = TextField(
            'email',
            validators=[DataRequired(), Email(message=None), Length(min=6, max=40)])

def validate(self):
    print "validating"
    initial_validation = super(RegisterForm, self).validate()
    if not initial_validation:
        print "not initial validation"
        return False
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=self.email.data).first()
    print user
    if user:
        print self
        print "error, email already registered"
        self.email.errors.append("This Email is already registered")
        return False
    return True
```

When attempting to debug, the value for 'print user' from this is:

project.user.forms.RegisterForm object at 0x7fa436807698

Comment: please provide your html template, looks like your request.form['something'] is not declared you simply decided to assign it to your variable "form" hence the object at 0x7fa436807698, you are not fetching the individual elements from your object

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and updated the html template

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, @glls, you were correct.Rewrote the code as:

```
@main_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@main_blueprint.route('/<referrer>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home(referrer=None):

    # prepares response
    resp = make_response(render_template('main/index.html', form=form))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       do_stuff()

    form = RegisterForm(request.form)

    return resp
```